# Prevent Transport Package being deployed

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1.  Content Delivery is in .Net.

We want to make only Transport Package available to Search engine.  This Search engine will extract required content/metadata from transport package and will index it.  Search engine is installed on different domain/Server.

To achieve this we want to configure a Publication Target which will publish the content to search engine’s server but will not deploy the content.  Only Transport Package will be made available in some folder (incoming\success).  Can we do it using HttpUpload.aspx and by disabling some settings in cd_storage_config or cd_deployer_conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that @Jeremy's approach is the ***correct*** answer, but if writing a storage mechanism in Java sounds too taxing, you could just allow the items to get published to the file system, and schedule a simple script to delete all the files daily/hourly to save disk space.

This would require no integration effort with SDL Tridion.

Answer (score 9):

The standard approach for this would be to extend the CD storage process. You can find a good explanation of how to do this at http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/extending-content-delivery-storage-sdltridion-2011-1.aspx

Comment: Agreed. Of course it is possible to just push the zip file and process it yourself, but firstly why parse that structure yourself if Tridion has classes that do this, and secondly, how are you going to report the status 'Success' back to the content manager? All your publish actions will be reported as failed.